# Secure database and webpage against modification

Tags: database, security

My website provides extremely sensible information (think of bank account numbers) publicly available through webpages and webservices. The customers may modify these information when authentified with a username and a password.

Any hacking intrusion that would successfully modify the entries of the database, or modify the information displayed on the webpage, would be disastrous, as account numbers might then be incorrect and money could be directed to a malicious bank account.

Do you have any general advices about the architecture that would make such a service as robust as possible? I would not be responsible in case of a weak password, so my main concern is about attacks that would simply bypass the authentication process and modify the database without triggering any alert on my side; it could also be the html code of the webpage that is directly modified to show different information...

Thank you

Comment: I think we need more information if you want help : languages used, frameworks, database...

Comment: Security is not just a matter of closing a few security holes and declaring "job done!". It's a continuous process that should be run as part of your normal software development lifecycle. It's absolutely critical to have a process like the [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Security_Development_Lifecycle) when you are writing software that stores this sort of information. There's simply too many possible attack vectors for security to be something bolted on as an afterthought.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't seem to be a specific programming problem. Possibly better suited for [security.se].

Comment: It is in fact not a programming question, but rather a question about the best practice in general terms. You're right, it would maybe be better suited for IT Security. I realize security is not a matter of closing a few holes; I'm not a security expert and have to give directions to my team though, that is why I need advices on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

In this case i would make sure to harden the system itself as good as possible. This includes a very broad spectrum reaching from Security Roles over transaction based usage of the database, logging as well as the prevention of all sorts of attacks like SQL injection, cross site scripting in general and maybe if its a that sensible system use certificates and general IP checks (like have a white list of IPs that are allowed to populate requests to the system that do not instantly get refused). Not to mention your Host architecture has to be protected regardless of the implemented security features inside your system (key words: firewalls, user privileges etc.). During the development process there should always be auto code checking software (like Sonar) running to detect logical errors and stuff.

Then it could also be a good idear to have a second system just to monitor your primary systems status. This system should log and notify you on:

- changes made to the system itself (like if someone has access to your business logic and for examply removes authentication logic)
- changes made to the database that are not consistent with your primary systems state.
- detect suspicious actions: Banks for example have rules that apply on your account. Like if you used to make payments within europe for the last time and then out of nothing make a huge payment to lets say china you would recive a notification to commit this payment. The payment then would not be triggered unless that second commitment of the customer.

In the end you already pointed out correctly that you just can harden it as good as possible but generally not make it "100%" safe (at least in theory) so to have a good level of security part of the total system would include beeing able to detect unwanted changes, identify the exact changes already beeing made and have information on the overall status of your system to allow a rollback or manual correction of a corruptet state in case it already happened.

Even after having implemented mentioned techniques you would have to continously check for security bugs in used frameworks, librarys and the system as a full (like using security penetration frameworks that auto try to corrupt your system).

What i want to show you with my answer is what the comments already suggest: It is a very broad and complex topic with multiple layers of security concernes you will have to either study yourself or have framework solutions that "ensure" you to take care of the topic (like Webframeworks often include basic XSS prevention).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The project hasn't started yet and I am not a security expert, I needed a broad overview of the best practices in order to let my team work on this important security issue. Your answered helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Without wanting to sound harsh, but if you have to ask this question on Stack Overflow, you're not really qualified to work on this project.

The financial value of your data sounds like it's enough for an attacker to expend significant resources breaching your defenses - and the consequences of such a breach would be disastrous for your organization and its customers; it could lead to the organization having to close down. You really don't want to be learning about security from strangers on the internet in this case.

One place to start learning in is with the established standards for managing financial information, often referred to as "[PCI standards](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/)"; these provide guidelines for hardware, software and processes for organizations that deal with payment details.

There are numerous books on IT security; I like the "Hacking Exposed" series, and "[Security Engineering](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html)".

You might also bring in specialized IT security consultants; I've worked with a number of these guys, and many of them are very good at helping you engineer security into your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. Just to be more precise about my situation, I'm managing a start-up which will soon invest in such a project. I have a team of developers who probably know a lot more than I do about security but as I have an engeneering background, I am gathering information in order to value their propositions and choices. It is clear that I couldn't do it myself, though, and that I cannot afford to dive deeper into security myself. That's why I'm hoping to get general directions by asking my question on stack overflow.